# Private jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, private

Is there a way to make unavailable for others jupyter notebook contents? I want to share notebook with others so it would perform the necessary actions but users couldn’t see the inside code.

Comment: You'd probably have to compile the program as an executable.  Not necessarily a simple process.   Are your users running a program you wrote in the notebook, or navigating and running individual cells?  Google "jupyter to executable" and you'll get a bunch of hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save the code that's performing actions into an appropriately formatted `.py` file, and import from that file the calls you wish to perform - you could distribute this along with your notebook and encapsulate your user interface (the notebook) apart from your logic (the code in the .py file).

For example, say in your notebook you have a function:

```
def do_things(df):
    # do all the things
    # many lines of logic embedded in code
    ...
    return results
```

To avoid displaying that code to your users, saqve it in a python file called `privatethings.py` and import it at the start of your notebook.

```
import privatethings as pv
```

As long as it exists in the same folder as your notebook, it will be imported and allow you to perform the actions as a one-line block of code.

```
pv.do_things(df)
```

A suitably clued-up user might figure out they can edit the .py file, so you'd have to tell them not to do that if they want the process to work as you've designed. But that would be their lookout.

---EDIT---

Per conversation below, one (possibly dubious) way of fetching code from a distant resource might be to save it as some offline resource (say at a url, or in a scrambled text file) which can be fetched by the notebook.

Then, using the compile function, the python source code can be compiled into a form that's `exec`-able, enabling you to access functions that have been imported from a (relatively) obscure source.

Here's an example:

file privatethings.py:

```
def secret(string):
    return [s for s in string][::-1]
```

Save this file at `http://myloc.com/privatethings.py`

using requests:

```
import requests

url = 'http://myloc.com/privatethings.py'
r = requests.get(url)
source = r.text
code = compile(source, '<string>', 'exec')
exec(code)    # From here on, all functions in privatethings.py are available in this environment
secret("test")

>>> "tset"
```

Of course, executing code like this is problematic in terms of trust (and might be considered unethical in some situations) but since it was discussed below, the above is a minimal example of how such a thing might be implemented.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. Unfortunately, I’ll have to distribute my code/notebook to another user. In that case in order to work properly privatethings.py should also be distributed and thus visible to user. Or perhaps I am missing some points? Is there a way to distribute notebook with “import privatethings as pv” but let privatethings stay on git? Anyways after importing privatethings as pv the user will be able to read it?

Comment: If you can keep your privatethings.py on git, *and* if you can rely on its location remaining static, then you could potentially fetch it as an online resource. It will still be listed openly on git, but its location would be hidden by an additional level of obfuscation. I'll leave an example in the answer above. But security by obfuscation/hidden references like this can quickly be worth less than the efforts made to implement it.

Comment: Than I guess it’s better to make obfuscation by Cython for privatethings.py and leave it on the same machine with notebook

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible the way you said but you can save the output of notebook block. All you need to do is execute the block and remove the code after getting the output. In this way you can share the outputs without sharing the code.